# v-autocomplete: not displaying text &only using one letter as search-input

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-autocomplete

My problem is in a **Vue 2** application (migration to Vue 3 is pending, need Vue 2 at this time), that is built with Vuetify components.

**Versions:**
"vue": "^2.6.11",
"vuetify": "^2.6.0"

What I want to do:
I need to fetch addresses from an api in a `v-autocomplete` component.

This is the relevant part of the **template**:

```
<template>
<v-autocomplete
    v-model="adresse"
    :search-input.sync="search"
    :items="katItemsAdr"
    cache-items                        
    color="secondary"
    label="Von-Adresse"
    no-filter
    item-id="id"
    :item-text="(row) => {return row.name1 +' '+ row.name2;}"
    return-object
    outlined
></v-autocomplete>
</template>
```

And this is the **script**:

```
export default {
data: () => ({
    adresse: null,
    katItemsAdr: [],
    search: null,
}),
watch: {
    search (val) {
      const katApiAdr = `${this.$apiBaseURL}/general/address/${val}`;
      val && val !== this.adresse && this.fetchAdrDebounced(katApiAdr);
    },
},
methods: {
    fetchAdrDebounced(url) {
      // cancel pending call
      clearTimeout(this._timerId)

      // delay new call 500ms
      this._timerId = setTimeout(() => {
        this.$axios
          .get(url)
          .then((katRes) => {
            if (katRes.status === 200) {
              katRes.data.map((i) => {
                this.katItemsAdr.push(i);
              });
              console.log(url);
            }
          })
          .catch((error) =>
            console.error(`error msg katApiAdr: ${error}`)
          );
      }, 500)
     },
}
}
```

The HTTP request takes the search value from my input as a parameter to search the databse for the right address.

However two things happen that I do not want to happen:

1. The input that I type into the autocomplete field is NOT visible. You just can't see anything appearing there. I want it to be visible.
2. My input is registered though because the api request IS made. But only ever with one single letter. I want the input to be used as one string as in my example:

Let's say I put in 'boul' to search for some boulevard, it would delay for 500ms and then only look for the letter 'l' instead of 'boul'. The items (`katItemsAdr`) are then populated by whatever the api finds with 'l' as the parameter. The url for the fetch looks like this with the one letter as `val`: `http://localhost:8080/api/rest/intern/general/address/l`. However I want it to be `http://localhost:8080/api/rest/intern/general/address/boul`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague figured it out with v-autocomplete: **katItemsAdr** (the value of the items-prop in v-autocomplete) needs to be a **computed** property.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem but I had static data instead of server data. The solution for me was to change VAutocomplete to **VCombobox**.